# Require Accounting software

Tags: software-center

Hi Iam in search for a opensource Accounting software like Tally please do guide me regarding the same. This is for a Small Company

Comment: StackExchange has another sub-site aimed on such questions: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Accounting or Bookkeeping? Big difference. If you are not sure of the difference, then consult a real, licensed accountant in your country. Getting into trouble on your taxes or losing the trust of your financiers is not worth saving a few kopecs on software.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple to use but featured application downloadable free from the Ubuntu Software Centre is Grisbi. This handles multiple accounts and various currencies.

Answer (score 1):

**PostBooks** -- multi-user accounting / CRM / ERP suite (GUI)
PostBooks (*postbooks*) is a full-featured, fully-integrated business management system, the core of the award winning xTuple ERP Suite. Built with the open source PostgreSQL database and the open source Qt framework for C++, it provides the ultimate in power and flexibility for a range of businesses and industries of any size.

PostBooks can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories with the following command:

```
sudo apt install postbooks
```